# Split array by space into words

Tags: c

I got this code right here, which works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[100] = "Hello how are you";
    char newString[10][10];
    int i,j,ctr;
       printf("\n\n Split string by space into words :\n");
       printf("---------------------------------------\n");


    j=0; ctr=0;
    for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
    {
        // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
        if(str1[i]==' '||str1[i]=='\0')
        {
            newString[ctr][j]='\0';
            ctr++;  //for next word
            j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            newString[ctr][j]=str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n Strings or words after split by space are :\n");
    for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
        printf(" %s\n",newString[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

but instead of `char str1[100]`  I want to use an array of sentences`char str1[2][100]`
Meaning

```
char str1[2][100] = {"Hello how are you","I'm good, thanks"}
```

And these two sentences (or more) I want to be separated in separate words

```
char str1[100] = {"Hello","how","are","you"};
```

Actually, this is from a project for school, in which from a file, i have to store each sentence ended by '.'

If there is another way to store each sentece directly as words instead of sentences, it would be great help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LSIZ 128
#define RSIZ 10

void yodificacio(char* arr[], int index[], int n)
{
    char* temp[n];

    // arr[i] should be present at index[i] index
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        temp[index[i]] = arr[i];
    }
    // Copy temp[] to arr[]
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
        index[i] = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    char *arr[] = {"Hey","there","how","are","you","all","today","idk"}; **Here I want the input to be char str1[2][100] = {"Hello how are you", "Im good thanks}, instead of char arr[] ...**             
    int index[] = {0,2,1,4,5,3,6,7};                  
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    yodificacio(arr, index, n);

    printf("Reordered array is: \n");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf ("%s ", arr[i]);
    return 0;



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That result makes no sense. `char str1[100]` is just a single string, not multiple strings. What do you really want the result to be?

Comment: As you can see, the input is char str1[100] = "Hello how are you";

Comment: That's the input, but you want the output to be `{"Hello","how","are","you"}` which 4 strings, not 1 string.

Comment: I want the input to be char str[2][100] = two different sentences

Comment: I understand the changed input. I don't understand the desired output `char str1[100] = {"Hello","how","are","you"};`

Comment: That should be `char str1[4][100] = {"Hello","how","are","you"};`

Comment: To take multiple strings as input, you just need another loop to process each of the input strings.

Comment: Why doesn't the result contain `"I'm", "good", "thanks"`?

Comment: There, I updated the code.

Comment: The question still says `char str1[100] = {"Hello","how","are","you"};`

Comment: Isn't `str1` supposed to be the input, not the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an outer loop to process each sentence in the array.

```
int main()
{
    char str1[2][100] = {"Hello how are you","I'm good, thanks"} ;
    char newString[10][10];
    int i,j,ctr;
       printf("\n\n Split string by space into words :\n");
       printf("---------------------------------------\n");


    j=0; ctr=0;
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(str1) / sizeof(str1[0]); k++) {
        for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
        {
            // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
            if(str1[k][i]==' '|| str1[k][i]=='\0')
            {
                newString[ctr][j]='\0';
                ctr++;  //for next word
                j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
            }
            else
            {
                newString[ctr][j]=str1[k][i];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n Strings or words after split by space are :\n");
    for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
        printf(" %s\n",newString[i]);
    return 0;
}
```